# Хранение переписки пользователей в Телеграм боте

Tags: python, mysql, sql, telegram-bot, бот

Есть бот соединяющий 2х людей и переписываются они от лица бота, как сохранить их переписку в базу?
Возможно брать каждое сообщение поочередно заносить с меткой на id_chat, но в каком формате их сохранять? Или есть какой то более гуманный способ

Answer (score 0):

Хранить можете как угодно. Если это один чат то ID чата вам не нужен. Просто получайте каждое сообщение, получайте от кого и когда было отправлено и загоняйте в базу данных. Вам по сути нужны поля в базе date,username,message.

Comment: Может быть и 10 пар пользователей одновременно, мне не понятно в каком формате хранить сообщения, message, message.id, json, text 
И в последствии вывести все это в приемлемом формате для просмотра

Comment: Там пофиг сколько пар. У вас чат один. Вам достаточно получать отправителя и получателя.